# When does the browser, e.g., FF, send a CONNET method instead of client hello?

Tags: ssl, https

In HTTP CONNECT tunneling (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel for reference), the client/browser sends a **CONNET method request** instead of a **client hello** as in the direct https connection.

My question is can I force the browser to still send client hello if I put a simple port forwarder between the client and the destination server? Or what makes a browser know that it should send a **CONNECT method request** other than **client hello** when there is a HTTP proxy between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> sends a CONNET method request instead of a client hello

No. It first sends the CONNECT to let the proxy built a tunnel to the original server. Once the tunnel is established the normal SSL Handshake is done, i.e.

With CONNECT (i.e. proxy)

```
--- connect to proxy
>> CONNECT sslhost:port HTTP/1.0
<< HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established
--- everything from now own is transferred by the proxy to/from the target host
>> SSLClientHello
<< SSLServerHello
....
```

without CONNECT (no proxy)

```
--- direct connection to sslhost:port
>> SSLClientHello
<< SSLServerHello
....
```

Comment: Thanks! Got what you mean about using the proxy part and I also realized I I have mixed proxy and forwarder....A further question. Consider I have a client/browser, a https proxy, now I put a dumb port forwarder between my client and the https proxy. Will this system work?(⊙_⊙)

Comment: Since the actual target of the request is contained in the CONNECT request it will still work if you put a port forwarder or even another proxy between client and proxy.